# Largest and second largest number in array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

[image]

I have written a code in C++ for finding largest and second largest element in a array. Code works fine but the problem is location of second largest number is not updated. Although value of second largest number is correct but its location is not correct.

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int DATA[10];
    int largestNumber, secondLargestNumber, loc1, loc2;
    cout << "Enter 10 numbers of array DATA" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> DATA[i];
    }
    largestNumber = DATA[1];
    secondLargestNumber = DATA[2];
    loc1 = 1;
    loc2 = 2;
    if (largestNumber < secondLargestNumber)
    {
        largestNumber = DATA[2];
        secondLargestNumber = DATA[1];
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (DATA[i]>largestNumber)
        {
            secondLargestNumber = largestNumber;
            largestNumber = DATA[i];
            loc1 = i;

        }
        else if (DATA[i]>secondLargestNumber)
        {
            secondLargestNumber = DATA[i];
            loc2 = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Largest Number with location   :"<<largestNumber<<"    "<<loc1 << endl;
    cout << "Second Largest Number location     :" << secondLargestNumber<<"    "<<loc2 << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: In the case `DATA[i]>largestNumber` you should add `loc2 = loc1;` before `loc1 = i`: each time you assign `secondLargestNumber`, you have to assign `loc2`.

Comment: Note you do not need to keep values, positions are enough. This will simplify code significantly

Answer (score 2):

may I suggest a simpler solution?

```
#include <functional>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::set<int, std::greater<int>> s;
  int input;
  while(true) { // choose your stopping condition
    cin >> input;
    s.insert(input);
  }
  std::cout << (*s.begin()) << (*std::next(s.begin())) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: your code has possible UB, nobody says that values are unique. It may have different result as OP's code. Though it is not clear if OP's code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

if you only keep positions, not values, your code can be significantly simplified:

```
 int largest = 0, second = -1;

 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    if( second == -1 || DATA[i] > DATA[second] ) {
        second = i;
        if( DATA[second] > DATA[largest] )
            std::swap( largest, second );
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use "loc2=loc1" statement at first if block I think it will work ,check this code,

```
for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (DATA[i]>largestNumber)
    {
        secondLargestNumber = largestNumber;
        loc2=loc1;
        largestNumber = DATA[i];
        loc1 = i;

    }
    else if (DATA[i]>secondLargestNumber)
    {
        secondLargestNumber = DATA[i];
        loc2 = i;
    }
}
```