# Second or last but one

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, comparison

Walking through the code interviews of IT international companies I run into interesting problem.

How many comparisons do we have to make to figure out what element **out of six** is the **second smallest** or the **second largest**.

*None of these six elements have the same value*.

- we have main function with six arguments (v1, ..., v6)

  ```
   def solve(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6):
       # the worst case -> 9 comparisons
       if isLarger(v1, v2):
           v1, v2 = v2, v1
       if isLarger(v1, v3):
           v1, v3 = v3, v1
       if isLarger(v1, v4):
           v1, v4 = v4, v1
       if isLarger(v1, v5):
           v1, v5 = v5, v1
       if isLarger(v1, v6):
           v1, v6 = v6, v1
       if isLarger(v2, v3):
           v2, v3 = v3, v2
       if isLarger(v2, v4):
           v2, v4 = v4, v2
       if isLarger(v2, v5):
           v2, v5 = v5, v2
       if isLarger(v2, v6):
           v2, v6 = v6, v2
       print(f"#comparisons = {CntComparisons}")
       return v2
  ```

  which returns the second smallest or the second largest value.
- Determine this value by comparison (i.e. it cannot use indexing by that value).
- For pairwise comparison we can use only the below function

  ```
  CntComparisons = 0
  def isLarger(v1, v2):
      global CntComparisons
      CntComparisons += 1
      return v1 > v2
  ```
- Values are compared only by calling the comparison function **isLarger(v1, v2)**.

The goal is to find an algorithm that requires (even in the worst case) as few comparisons as possible!

Any ideas or hint how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Largest and second largest number in array C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388299/largest-and-second-largest-number-in-array-c)

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Comment: It cannot use indexing. Only isLarger(v1, v2) function applies for each comparison is allowed.

Comment: I'd write a selection sort and take the second largest/smallest. It's the most efficient way considering that the input number is 6.

Comment: The duplicate reference is not applicable here, since we may profit from the fact that we can either return the second smallest or second greatest. This could might mean a comparison could be saved in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial, but not optimal way is using the first two passes of bubble sort: this will swap pairs of variables and so bubble the 2 greatest values to the "right" and assign them to v5 and v6, and so v5 will be returned as correct answer. This requires 9 comparisons: 5 in the first pass, 4 in the second. So we have an upper bound of 9 comparisons.

A lower bound is 5, since that is the number of comparisons needed to find either the minimum or the maximum, and that will be needed to be sure a value is the second least or second greatest.

Here is an idea:

- Perform 2 to 3 comparisons to sort v1, v2, v3 through swaps from least to greatest. We then know that v2 is not the least nor the greatest.
- Perform 3 comparisons between v2 and the last 3 values (v3, v4 and v5).
- If these comparisons all give the same boolean result, it means that v2 is indeed the answer.
- If among those boolean results there is only one True (i.e. v2 is only greater than one of them), then let vx be the one among v3, v4 or v5 for which v2 is greater than vx. Return the greatest of v1 and vx: this needs another, 7<sup>th</sup> comparison.
- If among those boolean results there is only one False (i.e. v2 is greater than two of them), then let vx be the one among v3, v4 or v5 for which v2 is not greater than vx. Return the least of v3 and vx: this needs another, 7<sup>th</sup> comparison.

So in the worst case we get the result with 7 comparisons. The best case needs 5 comparisons (2 for the sorting step, and c4, c5 and c6).

Here is an implementation of this idea:

```
def solve(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6):
    # Sort (v1, v2, v3)
    if isLarger(v1, v2):
        v1, v2 = v2, v1
    if isLarger(v2, v3):
        v2, v3 = v3, v2
        if isLarger(v1, v2):
            v1, v2 = v2, v1
    # v2 is now certainly not the greatest nor the least
    # Check how it compares with v4, v5 and v6
    c4 = isLarger(v2, v4)
    c5 = isLarger(v2, v5)
    c6 = isLarger(v2, v6)
    if c4 == c5 == c6:  # All true or all false
        return v2
    if c4 ^ c5 ^ c6:  # Only one of them is true
        vx = v4 if c4 else (v5 if c5 else v6)
        return v1 if isLarger(v1, vx) else vx
    else:  # Only one of them is false
        vx = v4 if not c4 else (v5 if not c5 else v6)
        return vx if isLarger(v3, vx) else v3
```

I ran this on all permutations of `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and these are the results:

- 5 comparisons needed for 96 permuations
- 6 comparisons needed for 336 permutations
- 7 comparisons needed for 288 permutations

On average: 6.266667 comparisons

Comment: Thanks a lot @trincot, this looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the *best* element takes invariably `n-1` comparisons. The *second best* element is among those who lose the comparison only to the *best*.

By arranging an elimination tournament you guarantee that there are at most `log n` candidates for the *second best*, and finding the best among them takes `log n` comparisons.

Therefore, for 6 elements you need 5 + 2 = 7 comparisons.

As of expressing this in the code, here is a first round of elimination:

```
if isLarger(v1, v4):
    v1, v4 = v4, v1
if isLarger(v2, v5):
    v2, v5 = v5, v2
if isLarger(v3, v6):
    v3, v6 = v6, v3
```

Now next two matches are a bit trickier. You'd have to swap the corresponding losers from the first round as well, eg

```
if isLarger(v2, v3):
    v2, v3 = v3, v2
    v5, v6 = v6, v5
```

to maintain the invariants like `v2 < v5`.

After that the candidates are `v2, v3, v4` (or just `v2, v4`, if the leader `v1` was not displaced). In two comparisons find the best among them.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very good direction.

Comment: How it would work if I have e.g. solve(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5)?

Answer (score -3):

First of all if you want to find the kth largest or kth smallest element from a list or an array there are mainly two methods

1. Naive (Casual Approach)
2. Ingenious method (Modern Approach)

The naive method is to pop out the element each time after sorting for k times.
It goes like,

```
def myfun(l):
    for i in range(k):
        l=sorted(l)
        l.pop()
    return sorted(l)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach. There is not allowed any array or list implementation. Only usage of isLarger(v1, v2) function in every comparison is allowed to use.